# How can one increase Microsoft Outlook (Android application)'s cache size?

Tags: cache, outlook

How can one increase Microsoft Outlook (Android application)'s cache size (in terms of number of emails stored offline, disk space or some other measurements)?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: @Firelord not being able to search through all my Outlook emails when offline

Comment: There is no way except to keep as much space free as possible. Since Oreo, space quotas are enforced at filesystem level (based on UIDs). An app can use up to 90% of disk space or 50% of filesystem inodes. But apps exceeding their cache quotas are on the top of list when OS clears apps' cache due to storage running short. But it depends on the app how it manages its files. Emails can be maintained as a database (like we have on PCs) in non-cached directories on internal or external storage. Even user can be given option to backup large databases on SD card or USB OTG.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Gmail allows to increase how many days of emails should be saved offline.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that's what I said. It's up to the app how it manages its files and space usage, and how much flexibility it gives to user in this regard. But if it doesn't, there's nothing we can do at OS level, except trying some hacks with root access.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thank you, you are welcome to convert your comments as answer

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't think it's a proper answer. Feel free to answer your own question.